# How to use Scala's immutable data structures as members of a class

Tags: scala, state, immutability, mutable

I'm trying to get a hold on FP  and the concept of immutable data structures for mutable states. Though i get the idea "locally" like in a function, i don't understand how i would do it in a system.

I thought of an example to make it clear:
So in case i wanted to model a simple CPU-Scheduler for example, i would imagine doing so by constructing a class CPU with two members: a list of processes in line for processing, and a current process.

```
class CPU ( pending: List[Process], p:Process)
```

Additionally i would need some method like next() to change the current process. So now, how would i do that with immutable variables? Since pending and p are fixed, i can not reassign them.

Comment: If `CPU` is supposed to be immutable, then `next` would return a new `CPU` instance, e.g., `def next: CPU = new CPU(pending.tail, pending.head)`. The state is then maintained by the caller, which has to make sure the returned instance is not discarded.

Answer (score 3):

Once you work with immutable data, the mental model changes from *"how do I change this?"* to *"how do I transform this?"*

For you specific scenario, you'd want to add methods that can produce a new copy of CPU with the specific changes. Fortunately, using case classes, Scala does most of it for you by providing a `copy` method.

Now in your case, I'll assume that `next` should remove the next `Process` from `pending` and set it as `p`. I'll further presume that you might want the finished process returned as well for some book-keeping. In this case, all members are being touched, so it's easier to just create a new instance instead of using `copy`:

```
case class Process()

case class CPU(pending: List[Process], p: Process) {
  def next(): (Process, CPU) = (p, CPU(pending.tail, pending.head))

  def add(process: Process) = this.copy(pending = process :: pending)
}

val cpu = CPU(Process()::Nil,Process())
val cpu1 = cpu.add(Process())
val (finished,cpu2) = cpu.next()
```

For good measure I added `add` to illustrate the use of `copy`.

With this `CPU` is immutable and can be transformed into other forms. Your scheduler would likely still require a `var` to keep the current state of CPU, but that's another topic to tackle.

Now your the question might be, *why is this desirable*. One reason is that your data is now safe to pass around and be accessed from any thread, since it can never change and requires no synchronization. By going immutable on your data, the only synchronization you need is around processes that transform, rather than around the data itself and anyone that gets an instance of your data can be sure that it will never change from under them, but represent a snapshot in time when they asked for the data.

Comment: But i still don't have a system with a state, i only have "local" functions. It looks like i placed the problem in the caller function. E.g. if i'd like to run a simulation of my CPU to find out what switching strategy would be best, then i 'd write an object with a main method that consists of a previous defined list of processes and a loop that calls CPU.next while not empty. Since i receive a new CPU on every call of "next" , i would use a var here to store the CPU instance. So am i right to assume that it would'nt be possible to write this little simulation purely with immutable variables?

Comment: Not all problems are equally well served by immutability. If you have high state flux and require coordination between threads, traditional synchronization and mutation may serve you better. Most problem spaces that move towards immutability also move towards idempotent operations, i.e. immutability often requires a paradigm shift not just on one piece of of your system, but the whole.

Comment: if you were given the task, would you do it with a var in your scheduler?

Comment: I suspect for your scenario, CPU is primarily a FIFO queue of processes, with very little, if any inspection of the queue and in that case i would probably make CPU mutable and encapsulate the state transition inside of it. Doesn't seem to be a lot of benefit in immutable data for that specialized scenario

Answer (score 1):

Scala does not force you to make everything immutable. If you have a component that has a changing state, it's perfectly fine to model its state by mutable data structures (or immutable structures assigned to `var`s). The important thing is that you don't share mutable state between multiple complicated components, and use immutable fire-and-forget messages for communication instead.

Depending on how you set up your simulation of the CPU-Scheduler, you might also make it immutable. Then you would have to define the state transitions outside of the CPU-Scheduler, and store immutable instances of the CPU-Scheduler that represent your state. That would mean, that you have to create a new instance of the CPU-Scheduler in each iteration (this can be very cheap if you use the right structures).